# Pandas to SQL (via SQL Alchemy) yields Unicode Encode Error

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, unicode

I have these CSV files (top link to zip file from [here](https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Enrollment-by-Contract-Plan-State-County-Items/Monthly-Enrollment-by-CPSC-2016-04.html?DLPage=1&DLEntries=10&DLSort=1&DLSortDir=descending)) that I am trying to insert into an Oracle database.
I get this error when using the following code below. I tried encoding with utf-8 but no dice...

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdf' in position 18: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Code being used:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle as cx
pwd=input('Enter Password for server:')
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://schema:'+pwd+'@server:1521/service_name')
df=pd.read_csv(r'path\data.csv',encoding='latin-1',index_col=0)
name='table1'
df.to_sql(name,engine,if_exists='append')
```

When I just open the csv file via pd.read_csv, it works just fine in my Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed to use the encoding='latin-1' argument in create_engine.